# Search Kit - rewrite date to display one week earlier

Tags: searchkit, dates

How can I rewrite the date in search kit so that it displays a date '7 days prior'? Field is [start_date] of an event.  One week before is the deadline for submissions.  I just want to display that date.

Any insight appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works as a rewrite rule for a search display but see caveats below. Replace the Y-m-d with whatever date format you like.

`{capture assign="step1"}{"[start_date]"|date_format:"%s"}{/capture}{capture assign="step2"}{$step1-7*24*60*60}{/capture}{$step2|date_format:"%Y-%m-%d"}`

Caveats:

- Will eventually stop working in a future version of php (the date_format modifier uses strftime which is deprecated in php 8)
- In certain rare situations in leap years and for dates crossing DST boundaries it may be off by 1 day.
- "%s" isn't available on all systems (e.g. windows)

The last two may not be of much concern. The first one depends on how aggressively you like to update php version.

Comment: thank you!  That's a great answer, and it works beautifully.  The only issue that I'll need to eventually deal with is php8, and I'm sure there will be a workaround. Much appreciated!